# Как нужно компилировать java-проект для x64

Tags: java, компиляция

Привет.
Такой, вроде, простой вопрос.

Локально у меня стоит `x32 Win7 + jdk1.7.0_60 x32`.

На сервере стоит `x64 Windows Server 2012 + jdk1.7.0_45 x64`.

Вопрос: если я соберу проект локально (через idea 13.1) и выложу на сервер, какие могут быть проблемы при этом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никаких. Байткод не зависит от архитектуры процессора.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А версия в данном случае тоже не повлияет?

Comment: @kidar2 желательно в разработке иметь такую же версию JVM, как и на сервере. Бывали случаи, когда очередной апдейт JDK ломал рабочий код, например http://jaxenter.com/java-security-patch-breaks-guava-library-49360.html .